# Flask 404 Not Found

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to run my code, but when I click on the link I get `404: Not Found`. Here's my code:

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify,render_template,request
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

tempusage = 0
weightsusage = 0
curencyusage = 0
cost = 0
userip = '1.1.1.1'

@app.route('/tempreature/c2f/<int:temp>', methods=['GET'])
def c2f(temp):
    tempreature = temp
    ftemp = (tempreature * (9/5)) + 32
    tempreatures = [
    {
        'conversionType': u'Tempreature',
        'from': u'Celcius',
        'fromValue':tempreature,
        'to' : u'Faherenheit',
        'tovalue':ftemp
    }]
    global userip
    userip = request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
    global tempusage
    if userip == request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']:
       tempusage  += 1

    return jsonify({'tempreatures':  tempreatures})

@app.route('/tempreature/f2c/<int:temp>', methods=['GET'])
def f2c(temp):
    tempreature = (temp -32)*(5/9)
    ftemp = tempreature/10
    tempreatures = [
    {
        'conversionType': u'Tempreature',
        'from': u'Faherenheit',
        'fromValue':tempreature,
        'to' : u'Celcius',
        'tovalue':ftemp
    }]
    global tempusage
    global userip
    userip = request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
    if userip == request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']:
       tempusage += 1

    return jsonify({'tempreatures':  tempreatures})

@app.route('/weight/k2p/<int:w>', methods=['GET'])
def k2p(w):
    weight = w*2.205
    fweight= w/10
    weights = [
    {
        'conversionType': u'Weight',
        'from': u'kg',
        'fromValue':weight,
        'to' : u'pounds',
        'tovalue':fweight
    }]
    global userip
    userip = request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
    global weightsusage
    if userip == request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']:
      weightsusage += 1

    return jsonify({'weights': weights})

@app.route('/weight/p2k/<int:w>', methods=['GET'])
def p2k(w):
    weight = w/2.205
    fweight= w/10
    weights = [
    {
        'conversionType': u'Weight',
        'from': u'pounds',
        'fromValue':weight,
        'to' : u'kg',
        'tovalue':fweight
    }]
    global userip
    userip = request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
    global weightsusage
    if userip == request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']:
      weightsusage += 1

    return jsonify({'weights': weights})

@app.route('/currency/USD/EUR/<int:value>', methods=['GET'])
def usd2e(value):
    usd = value
    eur = usd *0.88
    cvalues = [
     {
        'conversionType': u'Currency',
        'from': u'USD',
        'fromValue':usd,
        'to' : u'EUR',
        'tovalue':eur
     }]
    global userip
    userip = request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
    global curencyusage
    if userip == request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']:
            curencyusage += 1

    return jsonify({'currency': cvalues})

@app.route('/currency/EUR/USD<int:value>', methods=['GET'])
def e2usd(value):
    eur = value
    usd = eur* 1.14
    cvalues = [
    {
        'conversionType': u'Currency',
        'from': u'EUR',
        'fromValue':eur,
        'to' : u'USD',
        'tovalue':usd
    }]
    global userip
    userip = request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
    global curencyusage
    if userip == request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']:
            curencyusage += 1

    return jsonify({'currency': cvalues})


@app.route('/billing/', methods=['GET'])
def billing():
 global userip
 global cost
 global tempusage
 global weightsusage
 global curencyusage
 totalusage = tempusage + weightsusage + curencyusage
 userip = request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
 if userip == request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']:
    cost = tempusage * 0.05 + weightsusage* 0.10 + curencyusage * 0.15
 return render_template('billing.html', userip = userip, tempusage = tempusage, weightusage = weightsusage, curencyusage= curencyusage, totalusage= totalusage, cost = cost)

@app.route('/useripbill/', methods=['GET'])
def totalbill():
  global userip
  global cost
  global tempusage
  global weightsusage
  global curencyusage
  totalusage = tempusage + weightsusage + curencyusage
  userip = request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
  cost = tempusage * 0.05 + weightsusage* 0.10 + curencyusage * 0.15
  bill = [{
        'userip': userip,
        'tempusage': tempusage,
        'weightusage':weightsusage ,
        'currencyusage' :  curencyusage,
        'totalusage' : totalusage,
        'cost':cost 
    }]
  return jsonify({'bill': bill})



----------
```

I get this in the terminal:

```
* Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2018 16:15:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple one, but even after fifty years programming I make mistakes like this. You might find your Python is working perfectly, but you haven't provided a route for the URL you were trying to access! You should decorate some function with

```
@app.route('/')
```

In that function you could render a home page.

Comment: So i added @app.route(`http://127.0.0.1:5000//weight/k2p/<int:w>`) and still an error

Comment: The link Flask gives you takes you to http://127.0.0.1:5000/, not http://127.0.0.1:5000//weight/k2p/<int:w>. What happens if you just add a route to '/'?

Comment: And what happens if you literally follow the advice in my answer above? Alternatively, try visiting `http;//localhost:5000/billing`, for which you _have_ established a route.

Answer (score 1):

Try just to add `@app.route('/')`, without anything else in the route, for one of your functions.

Comment: Have you tried to set the environment to development ? `$ FLASK_ENV=development flask run`